# C Macro pass number instead of a variable

Tags: c, function, variables, macros, arguments

I want to define macros with static numbers instead of variables as the argument.
This macro compiles.

```
#define foo(a) global_variable=a
```

But this doesn't compile.

```
#define foo(1) global_variable=96
#define foo(2) global_variable=117
...
#define foo(53) global_variable=20
```

I'm precomputing values that correspond to the passed number. For example I want the compiler to substitute *`global_variable=96`* if *`foo(1)`* is used every where in the code. Is that possible?

Comment: Do you intend to use the macro as `foo(1)` or some `foo(x)`?

Comment: Intending to use foo(1)

Comment: could you tell me more reasons why you really need to use `foo(1)` ?

Comment: The calculation to find global_variable takes many instructions. This is running on a embedded micro and it will be too slow to compute on the fly

Comment: @Peter ok then just find my answer.

Comment: @Peter macros are not going to make your code faster in any way. It's just token substitution that happens before compiling. It is __exactly__ the same as writing `global_variable=96` instead of `foo(1)`. If your expression for `global_variable` is complicated, it is going to take time even if you use macros.

Comment: @Ajay In this case computing the value of 96 is the slow part. Thats why I want to precompute insead of calling foo(a) and calculating a complex expression every time. The solution that you and Nik wrote is what I was looking for. Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As conveyed in the comments, you intend to use the macros as `foo(1)` and not using some variable `foo(x)`. This can be done.

This is an addition to [Joy Allen's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50980450/2858773).

First you define macros for each value as -

```
#define foo_1 global_variable=96
#define foo_2 global_variable=117
...
#define foo_53 global_variable=20
```

Now you need one macro which will actually be used.

```
#define foo(a) foo_##a
```

Now you can use `foo(53)` and it will be substituted with `global_variable=20`.

If you invoke the macro with a value which is not in the list defined, you will get a macro substitution error.

Answer (score 0):

Just define as follows:

```
#define FOO_1 global_variable=96
#define FOO_2 global_variable=117
...
#define FOO_3 global_variable=20
```

Comment: *For example I want the compiler to substitute global_variable=96 if foo(1) is used every where in the code. Is that possible?* -- doesn't answer the question

Comment: Thanks. Thats a way around but I wanted to know if there is a way to use the function syntax

Answer (score 0):

```
#define foo(x) foo_##x
#define foo_1 global_variable=96
```